# Rest-api call is not sent in Angular 6 and RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, angular-httpclient

I have this method in the **component**:

```
saveItem() {
   return this.itemService.updateItem(this.item)
     .pipe(
       tap((data: any) => {
         this.toastr.success('Saved');
       }),
       catchError((error: any) => {
       return throwError(error.error);
      }
    )
  )
}
```

And this is the function inside the **itemService**:

```
updateItem(item: Item) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.updateItemUrl, {
        item: item
    });
}
```

If I put a breakpoint inside the saveItem() on the line 'return this.itemService.updateItem(this.item)', and if I put a breakpoint inside the updateItem() on the line 'return this.http...', it correctly goes and stop into the breakpoints...
But I have the following **issue**: the rest-api calling is not triggered, and the http call is not sent.. in fact, if a I put a breakpoint inside the .pipe() operator, it doesn't go inside. Why?

Comment: Do you *subscribe* to that anywhere? Either in the component class, or in the template with `| async`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observables (like http-Requests) get only active when they have at least one subscriber.

=> No Subscriber => No Http-Request

You can subscribe explicitly by

```
myObservable.subscribe()
```

or implicitly by the async pipe in the html template

```
<span> {{ myObservable | async }} </span>
```

warm regards

Comment: I added:
       .pipe(
             ........
        )
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
      })'

So the .pipe() operator is useless? Where should I put the logic of the show toaster/return error?

Comment: the 'pipe(....)' operator is for doing operations on the stream. They operate onthe stream, but they do not "start" it.

Comment: So for example if the service gives me back the number 2, and I want to duplicate it before to show it into the View, I should use pipe() and then maybe a map() to duplicaticate the number, and then with the 'subscribe' I just return back the formatted result to the View? Or it is useless, and I should duplicate it directly into the .subscribe()? Or is it the same?

Comment: From the result it is the same. But sometimes you may want to provide a method that returns an observable. Then you would use the pipe in the method. As a result, for those who subscribe to your method all will get the "modified" data. Also, i personaly like to move all data manipulation into the pipe and make use of the pipe methods (map, tap,...). I think that my code gets better readable by that.